# using customErrors for vanity URLs / asp.net url redirection

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-6, http-status-code-404

So, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346761/url-rewriting-redirects-with-querystring/1346809#1346809)...

> In ASP.NET, you have a choice about how to respond to that - it's in the web.config as CustomErrors. Turn that on, then redirect to a fancy 404 page (maybe you already do). The fancy 404 page, then, could be checking the requested querystring (which gets passed over to the custom error page as yet another querystring) to see if it's a valid redirect, lives in your database, etc. Just do a Response.Redirect() from there.

Then [schooner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66420/schooner) writes:

> Thanks, we do have a 404 now but we would prefer this not to be detected as a 404 in the process. We would like ot handle it directly and seperately if possible.

..and I'd like to know just how bad a practice this is.  I don't expect to put my "pretty" URLs on the internet (just business cards) and I have a sample of 404-redirecting-to-a-helpful-site code working, but I don't want to get to production and have an issue with a browser that takes the initial 404 too seriously.  Can anyone help me understand more about why I wouldn't want to use customErrors / 404 to flow users to the page they actually wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with using customeErrors as your 404 error handler is that every time customErrors picks up an errored request rather than throwing a 404 error back to your browser and letting your browser know there was a bad request, it instead returns a 302 which indicates that a page has been relocated to whatever your customErrors page is. This isn't bad for most users because they don't know or even notice the difference, the problem comes from the fact that web crawlers DO know the difference and the status code they receive directly affects how their indexing works.

Consider the scenario where you have a page at http://mysite.com/MyAwesomePageAboutStuff.aspx for some period of time and then one day you decide you no longer need it and delete the file. If Google or some other crawler has already indexed that URL and goes back to it after you delete it the crawler will get a 302 status code instead of a 404 error and because of this status code the crawler will update the page's url to point to your error page rather deleting the non-existent link. Now, whenever someone finds that url by way of a search engine they'll end up at your error page.

It's not really a huge issue, but you can definitely see the headaches this can create for your users in the long run.

[Look here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3626149.htm) for some corroborating data.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I think I'm okay rolling the dice on this project, but thanks for outlining some of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

I created a vanity url system using the 404 as the handler. There's no need for a 302 on my side as the 404 dynamically loads the content and returns that. I am fully able to handle any and all POST / GET and SERVER data.

Works great. If you are interested TarantulaHawk is up on SourceForge.